# What is an expressive and efficient way to vectorize seq in R

Tags: r

I am aware of seq, which used in this way:

```
seq(by=1, to=3, by=1)
```

will get you from c(1) to

c(1,2,3)

How can I vectorize this behavior to go from

Input:

```
c(1,1,1)
```

Output:

```
 c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `rep` and it is vectorized.   No need to use loops

```
rep(seq_along(v1), each = length(v1))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

---

Or another option is `replicate`

```
c(t(replicate(3, seq(1, 3, 1))))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

---

If we wanted to vectorize the `seq`, use `Vectorize`

```
c(t(Vectorize(function(x) seq(x, 3, 1))(v1)))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`seq` isn't vectorised. You could use one of the loops to get the same behavior.

For example, with `mapply`

```
x <- c(1,1,1)
c(t(mapply(seq, x, 3)))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

If you want every sequence go till `length(x)` use that instead of hard-coded 3.

---

Besides, if your `x` will always start with 1 as shown in the example you can use `rep` and `sequence`

```
sort(sequence(rep(length(x), length(x))))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```